# Why can ++i ever be different from i+=1 performance-wise

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

Apparently after reading the old title that was

> Why do questions like `is ++i fster than i+=1` even exist

people didn't bother to read the question itself thoroughly.

The question was **not** about people's reasons for asking that! It was about why would a compiler ever make a difference between `++i` and `i+=1`, and are there any possible scenarios where that would make sense. While I appreciate all your witty and profound comments, my question was not about it.

---

Well, alright, let me try to put the question it in another way, I hope my English is good enough and I can express myself without being misunderstood this time, so **please read it**. Let's say someone read this in a 10-years-old book:

> Using ++i over i=i+1 gives you a performance advantage.

I'm not keen on this *particular* example, rather talking more or less generally.

Obviously, when the author was writing the book, it made sense to him, he didn't just make it up. We know that modern compilers do not care about whether you use `++i`, `i+=1` or `i = i + 1`, the code will be optimized and we will have the same asm output.

This seems quite logical: if two operations do the same thing, and have the same result, there is no reason to compile `++i` into one thing, and `i+=1` into another thing.

But *since the book author wrote it*, he had seen the difference! It means that some compiler would actually produce different output for those two lines. It means that the guys that made the compiler had some reasons for treating `++i` and `i+=1` differently. **My question is** why would they ever do so?

Is it just because it was hard/impossible to make compilers advanced enough to perform such optimizations those days? Or maybe on some very specific platforms/hardware/in some special scenario it actually makes sense to make a difference between `++i` and `i+=1` and other stuff of that kind? Or maybe it depends on the variable type? Or were the compiler devs just lazy?

Comment: Well, it really depends on the type of ``i``.

Comment: I think this belongs on meta.

Comment: I also think this would be an interesting discussion on meta. We seem to have had a recent spike in the number of these questions lately - some of which have been massively upvoted too.

Comment: U mad bro? I think those question exist because accounts "user1283817381289, reputation:10" exist, not that I'm saying it is a bad thing, but as Mike Danseglio said *"There is no patch for stupidity"*

Comment: Why do questions about why questions like “is i++ faster than i=i+1” even exist even exist?

Comment: Because people are not born with knowledge and because people are curious.

Comment: perhaps they exist because you can get 50 upvotes for a silly question like that...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'd ask it as a pedagogical question on programmers.stackexchange.com possibly. I don't think this is appropriate for meta, it's more about programming and attitudes towards programming than about the site itself.

Comment: @Flexo true, good point.

Comment: In C, i++ generally isn't equivalent to i=i+1 because the two produce different values. ++i is equivalent to i=i+1. In cases where the value of any of the three expressions with i isn't used, the three are the same. If it's a good compiler, it can optimize out the unused temporary variable produced by i++. Now, there are old books and old people around from the times when compilers weren't very good at optimizing. It's from there one can get an idea that i++ might be slower than ++i. Or it can be from a not so deep analysis of the matter. Finally, trolling is always trendy.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks, you seem to be the only one who read it to the end and saw that I was asking was about compilers, not about people who ask those questions....

Comment: As for the lazy thing... Back in the olden days computers were much much much slower than they are today and they carried much less RAM. Writing a decent optimizing compiler was possible even then. The problem was that the extra code for optimizing was making the compiler noticeably bigger and slower, costing more money and time. Further, developing and managing a big piece of compiler code with the rudimentary tools of those days wasn't much fun either. It's only now that you can have a nice IDE (and not one!) with a debugger in it, syntax highlighting, auto completion and all, SCM, SO... :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Question is reopened. Feel free to convert that to an answer now. :)

Comment: `++i` gives me a performance advantage because it's fewer characters to type each time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagine a non-optimizing compiler. It really doesn't care whether `++i` is equivalent to `i+=1` or not, it just emits the first thing it can think of that works. It knows that the CPU has an instruction for addition, and it knows that the CPU has an instruction to increment an integer. So assuming `i` has type `int`, then for `++i` it emits something like:

```
inc <wherever_i_is>
```

For `i+=1`, it emits something like:

```
load the constant 1 into a register
add <wherever_i_is> to that register
store that register to <wherever_i_is>
```

In order to determine that the latter code "should" be the same as the former, the compiler has to notice that the constant being added is 1, rather than 2 or 1007. That takes dedicated code in the compiler, the standard doesn't require it, and not every compiler has always done it.

So your question amounts to, "why would a compiler ever be dumber than me, since I've spotted this equivalence and it hasn't?". To which the answer is that modern compilers are smarter than you a lot of the time, but not always and it wasn't always the case.

> since the book author wrote it, he had seen the difference

Not necessarily. If you see a pronouncement about what's "faster", sometimes the author of the book is dumber than both you and the compiler. Sometimes he's smart, but he cleverly formed his rules of thumb under conditions that no longer apply. Sometimes he has speculated about the existence of a compiler as dumb as the one I described above, without actually checking whether any compiler that you'd ever actually use, was really that dumb. Like I just did ;-)

Btw, 10 years ago is way too recent for a decent compiler with optimization enabled, to not make this particular optimization. The exact timescale probably isn't relevant to your question, but if an author wrote that and their excuse was "that was way back in 2002", then personally I wouldn't accept it. The statement wasn't any more correct then than it is now. If they said 1992 then OK, personally I don't know what compilers were like then, I couldn't contradict them. If they said 1982 then I'd still be suspicious (after all, C++ had been invented then. Much of its design relies on an optimizing compiler in order to avoid a hefty lot of wasteful work at runtime, but I'll grant that the biggest user of that fact is the template containers/algorithms, which didn't exist in 1982). If they said 1972, I'd probably just believe them. There certainly was a period in which C compilers were glorified assemblers.

Comment: It for sure was possible with 1973 compiler technology to generate similar code (see for instance the much referenced [design of an optimizing compiler](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3093&context=compsci), the transformation is in the peephole optimization phase (BLISS is an untyped language more or less similar to BCPL) The compiler described here targets PDP-11 -- as the first C compiler --, but was running on a PDP-10, quite a bigger machine meaning that more resources were available.

Comment: For a point about 1994 state of compiler, at the time I started to use Linux for my thesis work at home. Reasons were that it was easier to make it work with the Sun I was using at uni, avoid the win16/win32 mess and a factor 2 in performance compared with Borland and Microsoft compiler I had.

Comment: @AProgrammer: agreed, techniques were known in 1972 to do the optimization, you can probably say that this *potential* is obvious to any compiler-writer as soon as an increment instruction is invented. Even so I think the statement "you get a performance advantage from X" would be justified if a typical compiler doesn't use those techniques. Or even if an atypical-but-lurking-out-there compiler doesn't, perhaps with some weasel words about "you sometimes get a performance advantage", or "you probably won't see an advantage, but do it this way just in case".

Answer (score 9):

In C, `i++` generally isn't equivalent to `i=i+1` because the two produce different expression values. `++i` is equivalent to `i=i+1` because they produce the same expression value.

In cases where the value of any of the three aforementioned expressions with `i` isn't used, the three are the same. If it's a good compiler, it can optimize out the unused temporary variable produced by `i++`.

This temporary variable springs to life because `i++` dictates the following 2 things:

1. the original value of `i` is returned by the expression `i++`
2. `i` gets incremented by 1

If you first take the original value of  `i` and then increment `i`, well, the original (now old) value of `i` has to live somewhere (memory or register, doesn't matter) because it cannot live in the now incremented variable `i`. That's your temporary variable.

If, OTOH, you first increment `i` by 1, then again, you have to create somewhere (in a register or memory) a value equal to `i-1` to undo the increment, so the old (pred-incremented) value can be obtained as the result of the expression `i++`.

With `++i` and `i=i+1` things are much simpler. These expressions mandates 2 things:

1. `i` gets incremented
2. the new value of `i` is returned

Here it's natural to just increment `i` first and then take its value. You don't have to have a pair of values of `i` and `i+1` (or `i-1` and `i`), old and new. New is all we need here.

Now, there are old books and old people around from the times when compilers weren't very good at optimizing. It's from there one can get an idea that `i++` might be slower than `++i`. The difference was observed in practice, not made up. It was real and some may think it can still be the case today.

One can also try to analyze the difference between the two(three) incrementing expressions and see that indeed there may be a need to do some extra operations and use an additional memory cell for the temporary variable in case of `i++`. And at this point the person may fail to see when this temporary isn't necessary or how to detect whether or not it's necessary. That's another possibility for questions about the said difference.

And, of course, people have loved trolling in all times. :)

As for the compiler developers being lazy... I don't think they were. Here's why.

Back in the olden days, computers were much much much slower than they are today and they carried much much less RAM.

Writing a decent optimizing compiler was possible even then.

The problem was that the extra code for optimizing was making the compiler noticeably bigger and slower. If it's bigger, fewer computers can run it, fewer programmers can use it to compile their code. If it's slower than other compilers, people will prefer other compilers because people hate to be sitting and waiting.

Case in point: me. I did have access to Borland's Turbo C/C++ in mid 90s. But I didn't consider learning and using C until late 90s, early 0's. The reason? Borland's C/C++ was much much slower than their Pascal and my PC wasn't a good one. Waiting for the code to compile was painful. And that's how it was. I first mastered Pascal and only later got back to C and C++.

So, smarter, bigger and slower compilers were costing compiler users money and time. At least during active development, which is still a very important product stage, even if the final product is compiled with a different compiler.

You should not also forget that developing and managing a big piece of compiler code with the rudimentary tools of those days wasn't much fun either. It's only now that you can have a nice IDE (and not one!) with a debugger in it, syntax highlighting, auto completion and all, Source Code Management, easy file comparison, Internet/StackOverflow, etc etc... And we can now have multiple 20+" displays connected to the PC! Now we are speaking productivity! :)

Really, we've got wonderful tools and devices today. 20, 30, 40 years ago people could only imagine or predict them, but not yet use.

Things were tougher. And, while I'm not going to make a statement here, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that back then when programming wasn't as commoditized as it is now, there were more good and brilliant programmers than there are today. And that, of course, is not in absolute digits, but rather in relative.

So, I doubt the compiler guys were lazy.

Look up the web for what's called `Small C`. It's a general term for a much dumbed-down and functionally reduced C compiler implementing only the most important features of the C language. You will find some implementations by `Ron Cain`, `James Hendrix` (early 80s) and others and derivatives from those (e.g. RatC/Lancaster implementation of the same by `Bob Berry` and `Brian Meekings`).

If you look at the code of any of those `Small C's`, you'll find that the minimum code size is about 50+ KB with 2+ KLOC, and that's only a translator from C to assembly code! Someone at some point would need to assemble that with an assembler.

I can't imagine comfortably working with such a project on something like an 8-bit home computer, e.g. a ZX-Spectrum (which I had as a child), which could have a maximum of 48KB RAM, the CPU ran at ~3MHz, all storage was on a tape recorder and the data transfer rates were like 10KB/min, and the screen was 32x24, not even 80x25.

And all that Small C code from early 80s, barely fitting into the computer's memory, didn't optimize anything!

Comment: FWIW, the very first B and C compilers actually had to introduce features *very selectively*, because there was a tight trade-off between how much bigger the extra cleverness made the compiler, vs how much smaller the extra cleverness made the compiler *when compiled by itself*. So some improvements were essential, others ruinous. When Unix "upgraded" to a PDP-11, they had 12k for the OS, and another 12k split between user programs and RAM disk. I assume the compiler was a user program. http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html "More history".

Comment: @SteveJessop Yep, that's the kind of tradeoffs people had to consider.

Comment: `there were more good and brilliant programmers than there are today.` That's a good point, but I would rather say that the percentage of good programmers among all was better those days. Now with IDEs that let you make interfaces by dragging pretty pictures and can auto-generate half of the code, there are a lot of people who came into the programming field, but don't really want to dig into complicated things. I believe that those days it was hard to even imagine how advance development tools will eventually become.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall The percentage is what I meant by `more good and brilliant programmers ... And that, of course, is not in absolute digits, but rather in relative.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what book you are referring to and, thus, can't look up the original quote. However, I suspect that the author wasn't really talking about built-in types entirely. For built-in types, the expressions `++i`, `i += 1`, and `i = i + 1` are equivalent and the compiler will most likely choose the most efficient one but for other types, e.g., any random access iterator, they are not necessarily equivalent. Semantically, they are meant to be equivalent but the compiler doesn't have this semantic knowledge and the implementation may do different things anyway. Getting used to writing the form which is likely to be the most efficient when using objects of a class types, even when using built-in types, avoids unnecessary performance problems: you are using the most effective way "automatically" so no need to pay too much attention.

When defining a class which provides the relevant operators, for example, when creating a random-access iterator, the compiler may not be able to determine that the code is equivalent. One reason for this is that the code isn't necessarily visible, e.g., when the functions are not inlined. Even when the functions are inlined, there may be side-effects the compiler cannot trace. The implementation of random-access iterators may very well internally use pointers and use `++p` and `p += n`. However, the moment the information that `n` happens to be a constant of value `1` is lost, it can't replace `p += n` by `++p` anymore. Although compilers are good at constant folding, it at minimum requires that the entire code is inline and that the compiler has decided that the inline function indeed should be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what type `i` is.

When the class is implemented, there are different operators for pre-increment (`T & T::operator++()`, post-increment (`T T::operator ++(int))`, addition (`T T::operator +(T const &)` (among others)) and increment (`T T::operator +=(T const &)`). (There are variants of all of these, obviously)

For trivial enough types, these are probably all of a muchness.

However, for non trivial types, the performance is going to depend how they are written. In general:

- `a++` is unlikely to be faster than `++a`, because it needs to return a copy of the object before incrementing.
- `a = a + b` is unlikely to be faster than `a += b` because the first requires creation of a temporary.
- `a += 1` is unlikely to be faster then `++a` because `1` might not be the same type as a, and there may be some expense involved and doing whatever is necessary to resolve that.
- For some classes, some of these operations might not be available anyway.

Beyond that, the only thing you can say with any certainty is that you should review the code and run performance tests.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about prefix vs postfix increments. I'd go so far as to say `a++` will never be faster than `++a`. (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/increment-pre-post-speed.html)

Comment: Depends how they're written and the class. I doubt ++i is faster than i++ if i is an integer.

Comment: Exactly so "`a++` is never faster and possibly slower than `++a`" would be far more accurate than "`a++` is unlikely to be faster"

Comment: i could implement the operators for a given class where that was not true. it wouldn't necessarily be a good implementation, but nonetheless it is possible.